how to use azure ai indexer with imageAction generateNormalizedImagePerPage configuration in search index?
I'm using this script https://github.com/microsoft/sample-app-aoai-chatGPT/blob/main/scripts/data_preparation.py and I want to get page number. I find out it can be done using indexer with imageAction=generateNormalizedImagePerPage configuration but I couldn't know how to do.
Azure AI Search
I did to find the way how to configure the indexer while creating index using above script.

I hope this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios

As mentioned in this documentation the imageAction property is configured in indexer configuration like below.
{
  "parameters":
  {
    "configuration": 
    {
       "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
       "parsingMode": "default",
       "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImagePerPage"
    }
  }
}

Then you will get the results in /document/normalized_images/* use it further in your image analysis, ocr or custom skillset as mentioned in this documentation
But the code you are referring is just creating index, so update your indexer with above configuration, you get the normalized members as mentioned here
As how it is done using OCR to get text and layout you pass /document/normalized_images/* to custom web api to extract page number and return to index.
